# How to get a 'feed export' of the files in an S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I'd like to create a database containing data extracted from files in an S3 bucket. I would like the database to remain 'in sync' with the contents of the bucket.

So far, what I've come up with is to create an `S3Processor` class which keeps track of the `processed_keys` and periodically updates them using [list_objects](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects):

```
import time
import boto3
import schedule

BUCKET = "my-bucket"
MAX_ITEMS = 1                   # Limit the number of files iterated over (for debugging)
FILENAME = "/tmp/temp.txt"      # Name of a temporary file to be processed

class S3Processor(object):
    def __init__(self, processed_keys=[]):
        self.processed_keys = processed_keys

    def process_files(self):
        client = boto3.client('s3')
        paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')
        page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=BUCKET, PaginationConfig={'MaxItems': MAX_ITEMS})

        for page in page_iterator:
            for apk_object in page['Contents']:
                key = apk_object['Key']
                if key not in self.processed_keys:
                    client.download_file(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=key, Filename=FILENAME)
                    # Populate the database with information extracted from the file
                    self.processed_keys.append(key)

s3_processor = S3Processor()
schedule.every().day.do(s3_processor.process_files)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The periodic re-running is necessary because files are constantly being added to the S3 bucket from a different source. It doesn't seem like an elegant solution, however, and I'm considering using [AWS Lambda Functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html) to respond to changes in the contents of the bucket. It is not clear to me, however, whether such a Lambda function would also work 'retroactively' on the files already in the bucket.

In short, is there a way to do this that better leverages the existing functionality of AWS/Boto3?

Comment: Adding an event to a bucket that triggers an AWS Lambda function would be an elegant solution, but it will **not** create events for objects already in the S3 bucket. Events are only generated from that moment onwards.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein you should repost this as answer imo.
You should have a one-off script that will retroactively execute for all existing objects and s3 trigger that will run a lambda function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more elegant (and robust) solution would be:

- Create an AWS Lambda function that is triggered by an **Object Created** event in the Amazon S3 bucket
- The function will be automatically passed the Bucket and Key for the uploaded object
- The function reads the object and adds information to the database

This event will only fire for objects added *after* the function and event are created. It can also operate in parallel if multiple files are uploaded simultaneously. Better yet, if nothing is uploaded, then nothing runs and there is no cost!